# Perl regex to extract seconds/milliseconds from a timestamp

Tags: regex, perl

I am wondering if anyone could give me help with writing a regular expression to extract just the seconds and milliseconds of a particular timestamp.

example timestamp below:

```
15:45:30.192
```

I am writing this script in perl. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There was an example of extracting the fields from a string like that in the `parse_time` subroutine in my solution to your previous question. All you need to do is ignore the minutes and hours values. And are you sure you want to drop the minutes? Without it an interval like `01:02:59.987` to `01:03:02.125` (which should be 2.138 seconds) won't evaluate properly because it will be just 59.987 to 2.125, which is nonsense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To get them separated do the following

`($sec,$millisec)=$_=~/\d+:\d+:(\d+).(\d+)/`

2. To get both second and millisecond in one variable

`($time)=$_=~/\d+:\d+:(\d+.\d+)/`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$timestamp =~ /:(\d+)\.(d+)/
$sec = $1;
$mil = $2;
```